# Is there any alternative sentence/questions generator tools available for input pharse/keyword

Tags: computational-linguistics

For example: "Please turn on kitchen lights". it should generate all possible and alternative sentence such as,
1. turn on lights.
2. switch off lights.
3. switch on kitchen lights.
4. please turn off kitchen lights
5. etc..,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even if these generators exist, they work badly. What could be the purpose of using such generator?

Comment: A program could parse the sentence and return variations of voice, aspect, tense, mood and elisions, but your examples go beyond that.  Are you testing an AI?